# Forcing Links in final generated PDF to open in New Window

Tags: pdf, iframe, hyperlink

Can anyone help me with this issue? I'm new to programming and now I came across this issue where.
I have Hyperlinks in the final Generated PDF(While Converting from RTF to PDF). When I try to click on the links in the PDF they are opening in the same iframe window Instead of Opening New Window.

I wish to have my Hyperlinks open in new window Whenever User clicks on the links. I am using latest version of Aspose PDF. I tried using following code.

```
inputFileExt = Utilities.FormatNullString( Utilities.getFileSuffix( srcFilePath ));
outputFileExt = Utilities.FormatNullString( Utilities.getFileSuffix( destFilePath ));

if ( fileDest.exists() )
    fileDest.delete();

Document doc = new Document(srcFilePath);
if((inputFileExt.equals("doc")||inputFileExt.equals("docx")||inputFileExt.equals("rtf")||inputFileExt.equals("txt")) && outputFileExt.equals("pdf") )
{
     PdfSaveOptions options = new PdfSaveOptions();
     options.setOpenHyperlinksInNewWindow(true); 


     doc.save(destFilePath, options);
```

I have also referred the links below where I could not find the answer.

- [Force PDF links within iframe to open in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885100/force-pdf-links-within-iframe-to-open-in-parent-window)
- [Opening PDF String in new window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript)
- [Open iframe PDF links in new tab (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687982/open-iframe-pdf-links-in-new-tab-chrome)